# Filtering DataGridView with TextBox (C#)

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to filter my dgv (via database), by using a textbox.

The problem I run into, is that when I enter a valid item name into the textbox, I get an error that tells me that I didn't enter a valid column name into the textbox...which is weird...because I'm pretty sure I have it looking for items by name, and not looking for columns:/

Here is my code:

```
     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //CLEAR CURRENT DATA IN DGV
        datagridview1.Rows.Clear();
        datagridview1.Refresh();

        Connection();
        sqlconnection.Open();

        using (sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM inventory_table WHERE Item= " + searchbox.Text, sqlconnection))
        {
           using (SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
                while (sqldr.Read())
                {
                    datagridview1.Rows.Add(new object[]{
                    sqldr.GetValue(sqldr.GetOrdinal("Item")),
                    sqldr.GetValue(sqldr.GetOrdinal("Quantity")),
                    sqldr.GetValue(sqldr.GetOrdinal("id")),
                });
                }

                sqldr.Close();
            }
        }
        sqlconnection.Close();
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: code looks fine to me... debug and see what are the values in searchbox

Comment: @Rusty That's the thing, I've tried just about everything I could make up:/ The only time it works is when I enter a valid database table column name. But if I enter a valid item name, it doesn't work.

Comment: You should use [SQL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: @Otiel Parameter worked:) Thank you!

Comment: @Otiel is correct that SQL Parameters is the correct way to do this.  But the reason you were getting that error before is because you weren't embedding your `searchBox.Text` within single quotes.  So it should have been `Item = '" + searchBox.Text = "'"`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are referencing the wrong column name in your SQL reads:

```
sqldr.GetValue(sqldr.GetOrdinal("id")), // Check that "id" and other columns are correct.
```

Double check the spelling and capitalization of those column references with what is in your database.